# How does F#'s async really work?

Tags: f#, asynchronous

I am trying to learn how `async` and `let!` work in F#.
All the docs i've read seem confusing. 
What's the point of running an async block with Async.RunSynchronously? Is this async or sync? Looks like a contradiction.

The documentation says that Async.StartImmediate runs in the current thread. If it runs in the same thread, it doesn't look very asynchronous to me... Or maybe asyncs are more like coroutines rather than threads. If so, when do they yield back an forth?

Quoting MS docs:

> The line of code that uses let! starts the computation, and then the thread is suspended
>   until the result is available, at which point execution continues.

If the thread waits for the result, why should i use it? Looks like plain old function call.

And what does Async.Parallel do? It receives a sequence of Async<'T>. Why not a sequence of plain functions to be executed in parallel?

I think i'm missing something very basic here. I guess after i understand that, all the documentation and samples will start making sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444676/understanding-f-asynchronous-programming

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A few things.

First, the difference between

```
let resp = req.GetResponse()
```

and

```
let! resp = req.AsyncGetReponse()
```

is that for the probably hundreds of milliseconds (an eternity to the CPU) where the web request is 'at sea', the former is using one thread (blocked on I/O), whereas the latter is using *zero* threads.  This is the most common 'win' for async: you can write non-blocking I/O that doesn't waste any threads waiting for hard disks to spin around or network requests to return.  (Unlike most other languages, you aren't forced to do inversion of control and factor things into callbacks.)

Second, `Async.StartImmediate` will *start* an async on the current thread.  A typical use is with a GUI, you have some GUI app that wants to e.g. update the UI (e.g. to say "loading..." somewhere), and then do some background work (load something off disk or whatever), and then return to the foreground UI thread to update the UI when completed ("done!").  `StartImmediate` enables an async to update the UI at the start of the operation and to capture the `SynchronizationContext` so that at the end of the operation is can return to the GUI to do a final update of the UI.

Next, `Async.RunSynchronously` is rarely used (one thesis is that you call it at most once in any app).  In the limit, if you wrote your entire program async, then in the "main" method you would call `RunSynchronously` to run the program and wait for the result (e.g. to print out the result in a console app).  This does block a thread, so it is typically only useful at the very 'top' of the async portion of your program, on the boundary back with synch stuff.  (The more advanced user may prefer `StartWithContinuations` - `RunSynchronously` is kinda the "easy hack" to get from async back to sync.)

Finally, `Async.Parallel` does fork-join parallelism.  You could write a similar function that just takes functions rather than `async`s (like stuff in the TPL), but the typical sweet spot in F# is parallel I/O-bound computations, which are already async objects, so this is the most commonly useful signature.  (For CPU-bound parallelism, you could use asyncs, but you could also use TPL just as well.)

Comment: Thanks! Serching for key terms you mentioned in your post, i found
here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/10/19/release-notes-for-the-f-october-2009-release.aspx that some operations have an "automatic return to context", so GUI operations as easier to implement. But if the programmer is unaware of this feature, it gets very confusing, because at first sight the code seem to be broken and yet it works.

Comment: Yes, there's definitely a trade-off here between convenience in the common case and overall perspicacity/transparency of the code/threading model.

Comment: Just a comment on a the statement that `StartImmediate` enables the capture of the `SynchronizationConnect`. It does not enable the capture implicitly, but simply allows the user to set a synchronization context in part synchronous part of the computation expression, and then later do something like `Async.SwitchToContext(syncContext)` to switch back to the UI thread.

Comment: Full sample how to handle switching onto `UI` thread with `Async.SwitchToContext` usage [Async.StartImmediate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.startimmediate-method-%5bfsharp%5d)

Comment: marcus' link to MSFT Developer Blog is dead but is archived here (look halfway down the page for the Async code): https://web.archive.org/web/20140416181124/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/10/19/release-notes-for-the-f-october-2009-release.aspx

Answer (score 12):

The usage of async is to save the number of threads in usage.

See the following example:

```
let fetchUrlSync url = 
    let req = WebRequest.Create(Uri url)
    use resp = req.GetResponse()
    use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
    use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
    let contents = reader.ReadToEnd()
    contents 

let sites = ["http://www.bing.com";
             "http://www.google.com";
             "http://www.yahoo.com";
             "http://www.search.com"]

// execute the fetchUrlSync function in parallel 
let pagesSync = sites |> PSeq.map fetchUrlSync  |> PSeq.toList
```

The above code is what you want to do: define a function and execute in parallel. So why do we need async here?

Let's consider something big. E.g. if the number of sites is not 4, but say, 10,000! Then There needs 10,000 threads to run them in parallel, which is a huge resource cost.

While in async:

```
let fetchUrlAsync url =
    async { let req =  WebRequest.Create(Uri url)
            use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
            use stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
            use reader = new StreamReader(stream)
            let contents = reader.ReadToEnd()
            return contents }
let pagesAsync = sites |> Seq.map fetchUrlAsync |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

When the code is in `use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()`, the current thread is given up and its resource could be used for other purposes. If the response comes back in 1 second, then your thread could use this 1 second to process other stuff. Otherwise the thread is blocked, wasting thread resource for 1 second.

So even your are downloading 10000 web pages in parallel in an asynchronous way, the number of threads are limited to a small number.

I think you are not a .Net/C# programmer. The async tutorial usually assumes that one knows .Net and how to program asynchronous IO in C#(a lot of code). The magic of Async construct in F# is not for parallel. Because simple parallel could be realized by other constructs, e.g. ParallelFor in the .Net parallel extension. However, the asynchronous IO is more complex, as you see the thread gives up its execution, when the IO finishes, the IO needs to wake up its parent thread. This is where async magic is used for: in several lines of concise code, you can do very complex control.

Comment: I think I am correct. I started with his question "Why not a sequence of plain functions to be executed in parallel?". So I predict that he is new to .Net, thus needs to see the motivation of async IO.

Comment: There is a difference between being new to .NET and the Parallel Framework extension library, and this question is more of the latter.

Comment: Yes, i'm not a .NET programmer.

The sentence below clears up a lot of things, thanks:

[[When the code is in use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse(), the current thread is given up and its resource could be used for other purposes]]

So you can't say: "after `use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()`, control returns to {the-caller|somewhere-else} until the response is ready", because it could go anywhere, right?

In the line `use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()`, what exactly does _the magic_? Is it `use!` alone or the `Async*` method has some special property?

Thanks for the answers, keep them coming.

Comment: Replying to myself: After some reading, i found out that AsyncGetResponse returns an Async<WebResponse> object and then `use!` runs it.

There are a lot of things going on! A list of sites which becomes a list of Async objects (which create another Async object for each call to AsyncGetResponse) and then the list is passed to Async.Parallel which returns a new Async object that is run, using Async.RunSynchronously! Wow, that's hard.

Answer (score 9):

Many good answers here but I thought I take a different angle to the question: How does F#'s async really work?

Unlike `async/await` in C# F# developers can actually implement their own version of `Async`. This can be a great way to learn how `Async` works.

(For the interested the source code to `Async` can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs)

As our fundamental building block for our DIY workflows we define:

```
type DIY<'T> = ('T->unit)->unit
```

This is a function that accepts another function (called the continuation) that is called when the result of type `'T` is ready. This allows `DIY<'T>` to start a background task without blocking the calling thread. When the result is ready the continuation is called allowing the computation to continue.

The F# `Async` building block is a bit more complicated as it also includes cancellation and exception continuations but essentially this is it.

In order to support the F# workflow syntax we need to define a computation expression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx). While this is a rather advanced F# feature it's also one of the most amazing features of F#. The two most important operations to define are `return` & `bind` which are used by F# to combine our `DIY<_>` building blocks into aggregated `DIY<_>` building blocks.

`adaptTask` is used to adapt a `Task<'T>` into a `DIY<'T>`.
`startChild` allows starting several simulatenous `DIY<'T>`, note that it doesn't start new threads in order to do so but reuses the calling thread.

Without any further ado here's the sample program:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

// Our Do It Yourself Async workflow is a function accepting a continuation ('T->unit).
// The continuation is called when the result of the workflow is ready. 
// This may happen immediately or after awhile, the important thing is that 
//  we don't block the calling thread which may then continue executing useful code.
type DIY<'T> = ('T->unit)->unit

// In order to support let!, do! and so on we implement a computation expression.
// The two most important operations are returnValue/bind but delay is also generally 
//  good to implement.
module DIY =

    // returnValue is called when devs uses return x in a workflow.
    // returnValue passed v immediately to the continuation.
    let returnValue (v : 'T) : DIY<'T> =
        fun a ->
            a v

    // bind is called when devs uses let!/do! x in a workflow
    // bind binds two DIY workflows together
    let bind (t : DIY<'T>) (fu : 'T->DIY<'U>) : DIY<'U> =
        fun a ->
            let aa tv =
                let u = fu tv
                u a
            t aa

    let delay (ft : unit->DIY<'T>) : DIY<'T> =
        fun a ->
            let t = ft ()
            t a

    // starts a DIY workflow as a subflow
    // The way it works is that the workflow is executed 
    //  which may be a delayed operation. But startChild
    //  should always complete immediately so in order to
    //  have something to return it returns a DIY workflow
    // postProcess checks if the child has computed a value 
    //  ie rv has some value and if we have computation ready
    //  to receive the value (rca has some value).
    //  If this is true invoke ca with v
    let startChild (t : DIY<'T>) : DIY<DIY<'T>> =
        fun a ->
            let l   = obj()
            let rv  = ref None
            let rca = ref None

            let postProcess () =
                match !rv, !rca with
                | Some v, Some ca ->
                    ca v
                    rv  := None
                    rca := None
                | _ , _ -> ()

            let receiver v =
                lock l <| fun () ->
                    rv := Some v
                    postProcess ()

            t receiver

            let child : DIY<'T> =
                fun ca ->
                    lock l <| fun () ->
                        rca := Some ca
                        postProcess ()

            a child

    let runWithContinuation (t : DIY<'T>) (f : 'T -> unit) : unit =
        t f

    // Adapts a task as a DIY workflow
    let adaptTask (t : Task<'T>) : DIY<'T> =
        fun a ->
            let action = Action<Task<'T>> (fun t -> a t.Result)
            ignore <| t.ContinueWith action

    // Because C# generics doesn't allow Task<void> we need to have
    //  a special overload of for the unit Task.
    let adaptUnitTask (t : Task) : DIY<unit> =
        fun a ->
            let action = Action<Task> (fun t -> a ())
            ignore <| t.ContinueWith action

    type DIYBuilder() =
        member x.Return(v)  = returnValue v
        member x.Bind(t,fu) = bind t fu
        member x.Delay(ft)  = delay ft

let diy = DIY.DIYBuilder()

open DIY

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let delay (ms : int) = adaptUnitTask <| Task.Delay ms

    let delayedValue ms v =
        diy {
            do! delay ms
            return v
        }

    let complete = 
        diy {
            let sw = Stopwatch ()
            sw.Start ()

            // Since we are executing these tasks concurrently 
            //  the time this takes should be roughly 700ms
            let! cd1 = startChild <| delayedValue 100 1
            let! cd2 = startChild <| delayedValue 300 2
            let! cd3 = startChild <| delayedValue 700 3

            let! d1 = cd1
            let! d2 = cd2
            let! d3 = cd3

            sw.Stop ()

            return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds,d1,d2,d3
        }

    printfn "Starting workflow"

    runWithContinuation complete (printfn "Result is: %A")

    printfn "Waiting for key"

    ignore <| Console.ReadKey ()

    0
```

The output of the program should be something like this:

```
Starting workflow
Waiting for key
Result is: (706L, 1, 2, 3)
```

When running the program note that `Waiting for key` is printed immidiately as the Console thread is not blocked from starting workflow. After about 700ms the result is printed.

I hope this was interesting to some F# devs

Answer (score 4):

Lots of great detail in the other answers, but as I beginner I got tripped up by the differences between C# and F#.

F# async blocks are a **recipe** for how the code should run, not actually an instruction to run it yet.

You build up your recipe, maybe combining with other recipes (e.g. Async.Parallel).  Only then do you ask the system to run it, and you can do that on the current thread (e.g. Async.StartImmediate) or on a new task, or various other ways.

So it's a decoupling of what you want to do from who should do it.

The C# model is often called 'Hot Tasks' because the tasks are started for you as part of their definition, vs. the F# 'Cold Task' models.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind `let!` and `Async.RunSynchronously` is that sometimes you have an asynchronous activity that you need the results of before you can continue. For example, the "download a web page" function may not have a synchronous equivalent, so you need some way to run it synchronously. Or if you have an `Async.Parallel`, you may have hundreds of tasks all happening concurrently, but you want them all to complete before continuing.

As far as I can tell, the reason you would use `Async.StartImmediate` is that you have some computation that you need to run on the current thread (perhaps a UI thread) without blocking it. Does it use coroutines? I guess you could call it that, although there isn't a general coroutine mechanism in .Net.

So why does `Async.Parallel` require a sequence of `Async<'T>`? Probably because it's a way of composing `Async<'T>` objects. You could easily create your own abstraction that works with just plain functions (or a combination of plain functions and `Async`s, but it would just be a convenience function.

Answer (score 0):

In an async block you can have some synchronous and some async operations, so, for example, you may have a web site that will show the status of the user in several ways, so you may show if they have bills that are due shortly, birthdays coming up and homework due. None of these are in the same database, so your application will make three separate calls.  You may want to make the calls in parallel, so that when the slowest one is done, you can put the results together and display it, so, the end result will be that the display is based on the slowest. You don't care about the order that these come back, you just want to know when all three are received.

To finish my example, you may then want to synchronously do the work to create the UI to show this information. So, at the end, you wanted this data fetched and the UI displayed, the parts where order doesn't matter is done in parallel, and where order matters can be done in a synchronous fashion.

You can do these as three threads, but then you have to keep track and unpause the original thread when the third one is finished, but it is more work, it is easier to have the .NET framework take care of this.