# Confusion about async in F#

Tags: f#

I am experimenting a bit with F# and I wrote a class that listens incoming UDP packets, prints them, and continues to listen.

I have four different implementations that all accomplish this.

```
type UdpListener(endpoint:IPEndPoint) = 
    let client = new UdpClient(endpoint)
    let endpoint = endpoint

    let rec listenAsync1() = 
        async {
            let! res = client.ReceiveAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            res.Buffer |> printfn "%A"
            return! listenAsync1()
        }

    let rec listenAsync2() = 
        async {
            let res = client.Receive(ref endpoint)
            res |> printfn "%A"
            do! listenAsync2()
        }

    let rec listenAsync3() = 
        async {
            let res = client.Receive(ref endpoint)
            res |> printfn "%A"
            listenAsync3() |> Async.Start
        }

    let rec listenAsync4() = 
        async {
            while true do
                let res = client.Receive(ref endpoint)
                res |> printfn "%A"
        }

    member this.Start() =
        listenAsync1() |> Async.Start
```

**`listenAsync1`** attempts to leverage the awaitable returned by `client.ReceiveAsync()` and re-listens using recursion. This approach feels most functional to me.

However, the async computation expression will actually run the code in the `async` block on a TP thread, so is it really necessary to using the Task based `client.ReceiveAsync()`?

**`listenAsync2`** accomplishes the same result as `listenAsync1` by using a blocking call on a TP thread.

**`listenAsync3`** uses a slightly different way of recursively kicking off the listener again.

**`listenAsync4`** uses a loop. It states intent pretty clearly, but is not really that pretty.

---

Is there an advantage of ever using Task based async in F#? It seems superfluous when wrapped inside an async computation expression which seems similar to `Task.Run(..)` in C#.

Which of the methods (if any!) is generally accept as best practice, and why? (Perhaps they can be ranked?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use blocking calls, you occupy the thread. That is, the thread is "busy" with your call and cannot be allocated for other work.
When you await a task, on the other hand, you relinquish control completely and the thread is free to go do other stuff.

In practice, this distinction will manifest in your application not being able to scale to a large number of threads. That is, if you make two calls at once, you've occupied two threads. Four calls - four threads. And so on. One could argue that this sorta defeats the whole idea of being "async".
On the other hand, if you make multiple calls simultaneously using awaitable tasks, your application may consume no threads at all (while the calls are in flight)!

Because of this, all three blocking versions are significantly inferior. Use the first one.

**Update**: you may also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541071/180286).

Comment: But doesn't putting the nonblocking call I an asynchronous block exactly spawn a thread, though briefly, just to kick off the nonblocking call?

Comment: Depends how `ReceiveAsync` is implemented. Any "sane" implementation would start the receive operation using the same thread passing completion continuations (like the old Async pattern in .NET). The completion continuations is then often executed by the thread pool.

Comment: @lejon - I think theres often a confusion that async = threads. This isnt necessarily true. IO operations usually go through hardware controllers that mean the CPU isnt blocking while waiting for dedicated hardware to do its thing.